# Joda-Time DateTime changes timezone?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am reading strings from a file that look like `"2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00"` into a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object. But `DateTime` isn't behaving the way I want.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

System.out.println("2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00");
System.out.println(new DateTime("2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00"));
```

The result is the following

```
2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00
2015-06-06T00:51:49.000-07:00
```

Later on I need the hour and minutes. Here that would be 1:51. But DateTime is printing it out in a different timezone I'm guessing? How can I get DateTime to print out `2015-06-06T01:51:49.000-06:00`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) stores a time zone, but the [`DateTime(Object instant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29) constructor first converts the `String` to an instant (millis), thereby losing the timezone information, so it applies the default time zone to that instant.

To retain time zone, use [`DateTime.parse(String str)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

```
System.out.println("2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00");
System.out.println(new DateTime("2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00"));
System.out.println(DateTime.parse("2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00"));
```

*Output*

```
2015-06-06T01:51:49-06:00
2015-06-06T03:51:49.000-04:00
2015-06-06T01:51:49.000-06:00
```

Comment: Ah yes, Joda's `Object` constructors.  Everyone's favorite subtle bug.

Comment: I suppose this confusion might be one of the reasons why [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) chose to go with factory methods only and eliminate constructors.

Comment: @BasilBourque The main reason to go with factory methods was the new concept of immutable value objects discussed by [John Rose](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/value_types_in_the_vm) intended for Java 9 or later. The problem here is different: `Object`-parameters are certainly not typesafe at all but the new factory methods in `java.time` with the signature `from(TemporalAccessor)` as a corner-stone of the new API are not really better, too, because of the general nature of such parameter types.